# Error maven PluginIncompatibleException in teamcity : The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2 requires Maven version 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, devops, teamcity

This is an springboot application and I am trying to add a webcomponent in this service. I am using com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin to install npm for my webcomponent. My application is working fine on my local environment with maven 3.9.0. But my application is failing in  production environment as it has maven 3.0.5 installed and I cannot simply upgrade the maven there.

Error I am getting on my prod linux environment:

```
[05:45:23][Step 2/2] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2:install-node-and-npm (Install Node and NPM linux) on project my-web-application: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[05:45:23][Step 2/2] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2:install-node-and-npm (Install Node and NPM linux) on project my-web-application: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2 requires Maven version 3.1.0
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:170)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginIncompatibleException: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2 requires Maven version 3.1.0
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:283)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:166)
[05:45:23][Step 2/2]    ... 19 more
```

This is the plugin I am using:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <downloadRoot>${nodejsDownloadRoot}/</downloadRoot>
                <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I tried all the fixes I could think of or find on internet but I am not able to resolve it. Any lead will be helpful. Thankyou.

Comment: The simple answer to this is: You have to upgrade your maven version otherwise you can not use that version of the plugin that's it... The other question which would come is: Why using such an old ancient version of Maven and why can't you upgrade your maven version? And what it mean in a production environment there is usually no build tool in there?